# What is wrong in my calculation ($x^{-1} \cdot \sqrt[3]{x} = ?$)?

Tags: exponentiation

I need to calculate the following product:

$x^{-1} \cdot \sqrt[3]{x} = ?$

First, I apply the rule

$\sqrt[n]{x^m} = x^{\frac{m}{n}}$

to convert $\sqrt[3]{x}$ to $x^{\frac{1}{3}}$:

$x^{-1} \cdot \sqrt[3]{x} = x^{-1} \cdot x^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Then I add the exponents:

$x^{-1} \cdot \sqrt[3]{x} = x^{(-\frac{3}{3} + \frac{1}{3})}$

$x^{-1} \cdot \sqrt[3]{x} = x^{-\frac{2}{3}}$

I use the rule

$a^{-\frac{m}{n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{a^m}}$

to transform $x^{(-\frac{2}{3})}$ to $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}$.

However, if I check the solution by setting $x=1$ and calculating both sides, it turns out that it wrong.

Where exactly (in which of the above steps) did I make the error?

Comment: For $x=1$ both expressions turn out to be $1$. It is correct your calculation.

Comment: When I set $x=1$, I get this expression: $\sqrt[3]{1} \neq \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1}}$. I don't think my solution is correct.

Comment: You haven't made a mistake in your derivation. You must have made a mistake in your calculation. $1^{-1}\times 1^{\frac{1}{3}}=1=\frac{1}{1^{\frac{2}{3}}}$.

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{1}=1$, so of course you are correct.